# Right aligned text in picture environment slightly off

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment

I'm making some placecards and using the picture environment to try to control exactly where everything goes. My problem is that, in the example below, the two lines are not exactly right-aligned. Any idea how to fix this would be very welcome!

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}

\newcommand{\rbox}[2]{
  \put(0,#1){
    \makebox(89,0)[r]{
      #2
  }}
}

\newcommand{\pclabel}[2]{

  \begin{picture}(89,51)(0,0)    
    \rbox{42}{
      \LARGE#1
    }
    \rbox{28}{
      \Large\textsc{#2}
    }

    \put(87,  0){\line( 0, 1){50}}
  \end{picture}
}

\begin{document}
\pclabel{Bob Smithm}{Fiji}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove spurious blank spaces from your code (one carriage return in text mode is taken as a space):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}

\newcommand{\rbox}[2]{%
  \put(0,#1){%
    \makebox(89,0)[r]{%
      #2%
  }}%
}

\newcommand{\pclabel}[2]{%
  \begin{picture}(89,51)(0,0)    
    \rbox{42}{%
      \LARGE#1%
    }%
    \rbox{28}{%
      \Large\textsc{#2}%
    }%

    \put(88.5,  0){\line( 0, 1){50}}
  \end{picture}
}

\begin{document}
\pclabel{Bob Smithm}{Fiji}
\end{document}
```

[image]